# Is there a way to evaluate multiple conditions in a single case for a switch statement?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

In a `KeyDown` event, I have the following:

```
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.V:
                if (e.Modifiers.Equals(Keys.Control))
                    AddRow();
                break;
            case Keys.Back:
                RemoveRow();
                break;
        }
```

Is there a way to collapse my first `case` so it'd be something like `case Keys.V && Modifiers.Control`? It looks really ugly with an IF nested inside of it =[

All I could find was fallthrough conditions which isn't really what I'm looking for, since I'm evaluating `e.KeyCode` and `e.Modifiers`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is not.  Case labels aren't "conditions" at all, so you can't combine them with other expressions.  I'd make a suggestion as to an alternative, but your existing code is just fine.